# How get password or hash password in Laravel in Adldap?

Tags: laravel, active-directory, adldap

I'm using the Adldap library to import users into a local database. When I try to look at the result of the dd() request, I see that the AD does not send the password.

```
$users = Adldap::search()->users()->select(['cn', 'samaccountname', 'objectguid', 'mail', 'useraccountcontrol', 'password'])->limit(5)->get();
dd($users);
```

Somehow to get the password or password hash and is this possible?

Comment: do you mean the column? did you check that the column in your table is also password? maybe this is case sensitive? Have not used Adldap so I cant give insight

Comment: Did you check that the model hasn't a `$hidden` property which contains "password" ?

Comment: @Mr.Kenneth, Yes, the password field is from the active directory.

Comment: @Takachi, Adldap is not exactly a model in the database; it is an interface for working with the active directory. It does not have the usual fields characteristic of the model, and therefore there is no hidden array.